# How to delete using javascript in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Need a little help in here. I just want to delete a row from database using javascript. But facing some problems.

Here is my view:

```
<?php echo anchor("#","Delete",array('class'=>'selectedpagination', 'onclick'=>'confirmDelete("admin/editpage/","'.$file->page_id.'");'))?>
```

And Javascript is here

```
function confirmDelete(controller,id)
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record"))
    {
        <!--location.href="main.php?page="+page+"&tblname="+tblname+"&fldname="+fldname+"&id="+id+"&action=delete";-->
        window.redirect("http://localhost/sama/index.php/admin/"+controller+"/"+id);
    }
```

How to make it work?? Its not working.

Please anyone or someone, desperately needing help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you try jquery ajax ? instead

Comment: You doubled admin/ in your URL: ...index.php/admin/admin/editpage/... Is that intended?

Comment: Plz would you give me an appropriate way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using jQuery's shorthand AJAX function [**$.post()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) to post data to the page you need like so:

```
function confirmDelete(controller, id){

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record")){

        var data = "page="+page+"&tblname="+tblname+
                   "&fldname="+fldname+"&id="+id+"&action=delete";

        $.post(controller, data)
            .done(function(data) {
                // redirect or further logic here
        });

    }

}
```

Server-side you receive each of your posted variables like:

`$action = $this->input->post('action');`

---

Besides the above solution, you may want to rethink your approach to this. You are sending data to a controller through javascript and then you redirect the browser to another page using javascript throughout the process. It may have been easier to just call the controller and pass the variables you need by the session cookie or through the url and when everything is done server-side, use codeigniter's `redirect()` helper function to redirect the browser to where you want. The use of javascript and AJAX here would be fine if you wanted to build an asynchronous application... but... ajax call and redirection rather blow the purpose of asynchronous calls. Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much Aleris Shyti for your answer. Actually I am a newbie so would you please show me how its done step by step. I would be more than happy. I am stucking on this since long time. Please please..

Comment: @BlueRose Where are you stuck at now? You just call `confirmDelete()` when you click a button like you have already and jQuery will post the string of data at your controller, just like when you submit a form, but the page does not refresh. The controller should read and store the posted data as I mentioned in my answer. Don't forget to include jQuery in your `<header>` by the way. If you have no experience of jQuery I suggest you look at it.